# Insert nested values into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, insert, nested

say I have a simple dictionary `d={'a':1}`

I wish to run a line `d['b']['c'] = 2` but I can't, I get: `KeyError: 'b'`

I don't want to insert `b` first with an empty dictionary because most of the time, this dictionary will contain `b` with more values except for `c`.

Is there an elegant way to do it so my final dictionary is:

```
d = {'a':1,
     'b':{'c':2}}
```

Comment: You have to create `'b'` first, then you can create `'c'`. Alternatively you use a `defaultdict` that creates `dict` types automatically.

Comment: Your simple issue as suggested by Klaus is that you are trying to access key 'b' first and then add another dictionary with key as 'c' and value as 2. If you don't already have a key as 'b', then of course it will give you error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is defaultdict sufficient for you?

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict()

d['a'] = 1
print(d) # this gives back: defaultdict(None, {'a': 1})

d['b'] = {'c':2}
print(d) # this gives back: defaultdict(None, {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}})
```

For a better example of defaultdict:

```
s = 'mississippi'
d = defaultdict(int)
for k in s:
    d[k] += 1

d.items() # this gives back: [('i', 4), ('p', 2), ('s', 4), ('m', 1)]
```

When a letter is first encountered, it is missing from the mapping, so the default_factory function calls int() to supply a default count of zero. The increment operation then builds up the count for each letter.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you don't want to first assign an empty dict in order to erase nothing, you can first check if the dict is here or not, it's not one line only but quite clear I think:

```
d ={'a':1}
b = d.get('b', {})
b['c'] = 2
d['b'] = b
```